# Why my "Elif" isn't working in this code?

Tags: python

When i run the code my "Elif" dont print anything at the terminal.
The code just continues as if nothing is written inside the "elif" quote
Im new to coding and i tried for so much time to correct this error but i just couldn't :(

```
import time

initialnumber = int(input("Insira o Numero inicial.\n"))
finalnumber= int(input("Insira o Numero Final.\n"))

while loop == True:
   
    
    counterinitial = initialnumber
    counterfinal = finalnumber
    print("Calculating...")
    print("\tResults of the Square roots:")
    
    if (initialnumber < finalnumber):
        for quadrado in range (initialcounter,finalcounter+1,1):
            result = inicialnumber*inicialnumber
            print("\t",inicialnumber,"-",result)
            numeroinicial = inicialnumber + 1
    elif (inicialnumber> finalnumber):
        for quadrado in range (finalcounter,initialcounter-1,-1):
            result= finalnumber*finalnumber
            print("\t",finalnumber,"-",result)
            finalnumber= finalnumber- 1
            
    if initialnumber == finalnumber:
        result= initialnumber * initialnumber 
        print("\t",initialnumber,"-",resultado)
        
    loop = False
            
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Can you perhaps clear up the code a bit and translate it? It's pretty hard to follow with the non-English naming, and it's hard to run with all those delays.

Comment: In cases of not getting a print like this, don't assume the `elif` is the problem.  Your print statement is also inside a `for` loop, so the `for` loop could be the problem.  If you had an informational `print` statement immediately after your `elif` line, you would see the `elif` was not the problem.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i translated a bit and cleared-up a bit of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the range is always empty and the for loop exits immediately:

```
    elif (numeroinicial > numerofinal):
        for quadrado in range (contadorfinal,contadorinicial-1,-1):
                             # ^^^ contadorfinal < contadorinicial as specified 
                             # in elif condition.
                             # Can't count down from contadorfinal to contadorinicial.
                             # Therefore this range will always be empty.
```

Should be:

```
    elif (numeroinicial > numerofinal):
        for quadrado in range (contadorinicial,contadorfinal-1,-1):
```

with the two counters swapped. Like this, it works.